# Copying and Pasting Column with Concat not Working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have one sheet in excel that I have concatenate values in. But when I try to copy the exact same column for another page it does not copy correctly. It goes from =CONCAT(A!C8,A!D8,"-",A!$F$5) to =CONCAT(A!A2,A!B2,"-",A!$F$5). How do I get it to keep the exact same formula? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You know the difference between absolute an relative references in a formula right? The $ symbol before a column in a formula means when you copy to the next column it stays anchored to the original. Without it it becomes relative to the last one. Ditto rows. The only way you can do what I suspect you want is copy/paste the actual formula entry bar rather than the cell itself. If you copy across sheets you may get a sheet reference prefixed that you may or may not want to edit out after pasting. That's the A! in your example.. Sheet A.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copy, then on the page you want to paste, "Right-Click" and choose "Paste Special" and choose "Formulas" ??